# Is there a way to create a mail enabled contact from a script in Exchange 2003?

Tags: scripting, exchange-2003

I've seen the newer cmdlets for 2010+ in Exchange, but it looks like the only way to do things in 2003 Exchange is through the management console.  Is there anyway to make contacts from a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ms870495(v=exchg.65).aspx

You can add a mail enabled contact by using vbscript for Exchange 2003 and cdo.